# Integrated welogic service get terminated:Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

Tags: javascript

I am facing below error while running Integrated weblogic service in JDEVELOPER 12.1.3

```
    A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000002f29043, pid=5036, tid=5504
#
 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b13) (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
J  oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLText.xdkGetNextNode()Loracle/xml/parser/v2/XMLNode;
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\10615237\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.3.0.41.140521.1008\DefaultDomain\hs_err_pid5036.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Stopping Derby server...
Derby server stopped.
Process exited.
[IntegratedWebLogicServer terminated.]
```

Comment: add error log file entries.

Comment: Please help me how to add my log file here

Comment: you have a report there C:\Users\10615237\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.3.0.41.140521.1008\DefaultDomain\hs_err_pid5036.log just past what is usefull

Comment: I am asking how to upload here,it is not allowing me to upload

Comment: Just copy paste what you think is usefull